# Count new lines from file doesn't work properly

Tags: c++

I am trying to count new lines from my file, but it doesn't seem to work. It gives me result 0 when there is 1 new line. How can I fix this?

```
getline(file, newstring);
char line;
int lines = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < newstring.length(); i++)
{

    if(line== '\n')
    {
        lines++;
    }

}
cout << lines;
```

Comment: You never assign any value to `line`

Comment: What do I need to assign to it? i tried ```char line = '\n'``` wont work.

Comment: @debooger3 How could `line== '\n'` ever be true if you never change the value of `line`? Don't you need to examine `newstring` if you want to know what it contains?

Comment: @debooger3 `getline` reads one line including the newline at the end, but it does not include that newline in the returned string. So your approach cannot work. But since `getline` always reads one line what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, this may also provide what you need:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("file");
    // DISPLAY number of `\n` characters
    std::cout << std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile),
                            std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), '\n') << std:: endl;
    inFile.seekg(0); // reset the inFile stream to the first caracter to be read
    /** this also works - thanks to @Armin Montigny for the suggestion*/
    // DISPLAY number of `\n` characters
    std::cout << std::count(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile),
                            {}, '\n');
}
```

If I have a file like this:

[image]

This would count `11` new lines characters.

Comment: Very good answer. You may replace ````std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()```` with ````{}```` in C++17.

Comment: Great, Thanks, I've added your suggestion to be more visible

Answer (score 2):

`std::getline` reads an entire line (and only one; it's called "getline", not "getlines") up to the line-terminating character, but the result does not include that terminator.

You don't need to look inside the string, you can just count how many times `std::getline` succeeds.

```
int lines = 0;
while (getline(file, newstring))
{
    lines++;
}
cout << lines;
```

Comment: In addition to this, if `newString` is only being used in the while loop and isn't needed before or afterwards, it may be a better idea to use a for loop like so: `for (std::string newString; std::getline(file, newString);)` so that `newString` is destroyed afterwards.